# A Problem from Pinter Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, automata

This is a problem from the book *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Pinter; chapter 6H (Theory of Automata).

[image]

I am unable to make any progress in this problem. I was thinking one can take

$$S=\{s_0,s_1,s_2,s_3\}.$$

[image]

But then why does this says whether the sequence contains exactly three $a$’s.

Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: I am guessing $S_3$ is supposed to be the accepting state, right? Why do you have an arrow out from $S_3$ to $S_2$? Also, you probably want arrows to itself for $S_0, S_1, S_2$ for each of the other letters in the other alphabets.

Comment: Is one supposed to indicate some state the machine has to be in at the end of the input to say that "it has three a's"?

Comment: Wont' you need one arrow for each input at each state? How would one know to transition otherwise? or is it implicit that no arrow means it loops back to the same state?  I guess the answer is no since you put a loop on the last state....

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to reply because of the bad internet at night.

Comment: @rschwieb could you please explain a little?

Comment: @Iampi explain what?

Comment: @rschwieb In that book it seems that there is no definition of what it means for the automaton to "determine" something. The example has no start or accepting state, either. Probably this insufficient definition is what makes it so hard for i am pi to understand the problem and find a solution. I recommend reading a book, where automata theory is developed in more breadth than on just one page.

Comment: @PeterLeupold Could you please suggest some of the good reference?

Comment: @iampi "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, And Computation" by Hopcroft and Ullmann is a standard reference with an approach from Computer Science.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in your diagram the arrows that aren't indicated keep you in the same state. I assume that $s_0$ is the initial state and $s_3$ is intended to be the unique accepting state.

There are a couple of problems with this automaton:

1. There is no reason for $d$ to take you back to $s_2$. For example, $aaad$ ought to be accepted but isn't.
2. Your automaton will accept words with more than three $a$'s.

Comment: I also feel that my diagram is not correct, but then could you say what will be the correct one as I am unable to make it.

Comment: It's entirely possible that your book will have special conventions I don't know about, but if not, I would expect there to be four arrows originating from each state: one each for $a, b, c, d.$

Comment: Yes, you are right. There will be arrows from each state. This picture is made by me, I might be wrong. What I was thinking there will be self loop from state $S_0,S_1$ and $S_2$ but then how do I know exactly three $a$’s are there in the sequence.

Comment: If you have an automation in your mind, could you please add it to the answer with a bit of explanation so that I can understand it clearly.

Comment: Your machine could have the following states: "I haven't read any $a$'s yet"; "I've read exactly one $a$ so far"; "I've read exactly two $a$'s so far"; "I've read exactly three $a$'s so far"; "I've already read more than three $a$'s." Can you figure out what the transitions ought to be for such a machine? Could you try to edit your question with an attempt along these lines?

Comment: You can cut down on clutter by adding several labels to the same arrow if needed.

Comment: Okay, let me try.